# Get function with generic return type

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, c++14

I try to implement a data structure that comprises multiple name-value pairs where values may differ in their type:

```
template< typename T >
struct name_value_pair
{
  std::string name;
  T           value;
};


template< typename... Ts >
class tuple_of_name_value_pairs
{
  public:
    /* type of value */ get_value( std::string n )
    {
      // return the value that the element in
      // _name_value_pairs with name "n" comprises
    }

  private:
    std::tuple<Ts...> _name_value_pairs:
};
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to implement the `get` function.

A workaround would be to state names as `integer`s instead of `string`s and use an implementation according to `std::get` but this no option here: the input type of `get` has to be a string.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Could you show desired use of your `get_value` function? In particular will strings keys be known at compile-time or won't be known until program running?

Comment: The string won't be known until program running. The `get` function will be part of C++ library API. The names are passed as `string`s since this will more convenient for the programer than using indices.

Comment: What would be the workaround when string is known at compile time?

Comment: it could look more or less like [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Nf47Vhda5ICjed3i)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly have in mind you cannot do what you want directly. C++ is a strongly typed language so type of function result **must** be known at **compile time**. So of course if the string you pass to the getter is known at runtime you're not able to dispatch function at compile time to let compiler deduce appropriate result type. But when you accept that you need type-erasure to erase the getter result type you could make use of e.g. `boost::variant` to deal with your problem. C++14 example (using boost, since c++17 variant should be available in std):

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template< typename T >
struct name_value_pair
{
  using type = T;
  std::string name;
  T           value;
};

template <std::size_t N, class = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct getter;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct getter<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
     template <class Val, class Res>
     void setRes(Val &val, Res &res, std::string &s) {
         if (val.name == s)
             res = val.value;
     }

     template <class Tup>
     auto operator()(Tup &tuple_vals, std::string &s) {
         boost::variant<typename std::tuple_element<Is, Tup>::type::type...> result;
         int helper[] = { (setRes(std::get<Is>(tuple_vals), result, s), 1)... };
         (void)helper;
         return result;
     }
};

template <std::size_t N, class = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct setter;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct setter<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
     template <class Val, class SVal>
     std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<SVal, typename Val::type>::value> setVal(Val &, std::string &, const SVal &) { }
     template <class Val>
     void setVal(Val &val, std::string &s, const typename Val::type &sval) { 
         if (val.name == s)
             val.value = sval;
     }

     template <class Tup, class Val>
     auto operator()(Tup &tuple_vals, std::string &s, const Val &val) {
         int helper[] = { (setVal(std::get<Is>(tuple_vals), s, val), 1)... };
         (void)helper;
     }
};

template <class T, class Res>
using typer = Res;

template< typename... Ts >
class tuple_of_name_value_pairs
{
  public:
    auto get_value( std::string n )
    {
       return getter<sizeof...(Ts)>{}(_name_value_pairs, n);
    }
    template <class T>
    void set_value( std::string n, const T& value) {
        setter<sizeof...(Ts)>{}(_name_value_pairs, n , value);
    }
    void set_names(typer<Ts, std::string>... names) {
        _name_value_pairs = std::make_tuple(name_value_pair<Ts>{names, Ts{}}...);
    }

  private:
    std::tuple<name_value_pair<Ts>...> _name_value_pairs;
};

int main() {
    tuple_of_name_value_pairs<int, float, double> t;
    t.set_names("abc", "def", "ghi");
    t.set_value("abc", 1);
    t.set_value("def", 4.5f);
    t.set_value("ghi", 5.0);

    std::cout << t.get_value("def") << std::endl;
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OxJEOz4ey566b8JP)

I'm sure you'll be able to optimise the code (e.g. make use of move semantics/perfect forwarding, etc.). This is only to present you how to get your implementation started.

Comment: Currently, since the types of values are fundamental (e.g., `integer` or `float`), the `get` function returns uniformly a `string` representation of the value (I think `string` is more familiar to most C++ programmers than types such as `boost::variant`). Do you think this is an acceptable workaround?

Comment: @abraham_hilbert Well it really depends on your use case. The answer I gave is quite general and it actually does "remember" the type of your result even though it is runtime dependent... `std::string` will definitly "forget" the type of your result but maybe in some cases it is sufficient...